# Apparent division by zero in the proof of the Factor Theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Part of the proof of the Factor Theorem from Calculus: A Complete Course by Adams & Essex goes:

> By the division algorithm there exists a quotient polynomial $Q$ having degree one less that that of $P$ and a remainder polynomial of degree $0$ (i.e., a constant $C$) such that $$\frac{P(x)}{x-r}=Q(x)+\frac{C}{x-r}.$$
> Thus $$P(x)=(x-r)Q(x)+C,$$ and $P(r)=0$ if and only if $C=0.$

The first equation is only true for $x-r\neq0,$ so the last equation would be $P(x)=(x-r)Q(x)+C,$ where $x\neq r,$ and so $P(r)$ would be undefined.

But the proof relies on having $P(r)=0.$ Is this a division by zero? If so, how is this allowed? If not, could you explain where my misunderstanding lies.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the whole proof. Most probably there's something earlier or in the context that makes case $x=r$ trivial or non pertinent.

Comment: Which edition of that book do you have? Apparently, there are at least nine.

Comment: Offhand it looks a little sloppy: the division algorithm ought to say that there are $Q$ and $C$ such that $P(x)=(x-r)Q(x)+C$, and the problematic displayed equation need never appear at all.

Comment: This is a statement about polynomials and quotients of polynomials, not about what happens when one substitutes values into the polynomials: and the *polynomial* $x-r$ is of degree $1$ and definitely not $0$. But I agree with @BrianM.Scott, the division algorithm ought not be expressed the way it is in your book.

Comment: @J.G. I’m using the 9th edn.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I can see now that it’s not a division by zero. But am I right in my analysis that, as presented in the book, $r$ cannot be in the domain of the function $P$?

Comment: In case it's valuable, here's a different proof. Since $x^n=(x-a)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k+a^n$, all monomial $P$ are of the form $(x-a)Q(x)+P(a)$ for some polynomial $Q$. This extends to all polynomial $P$ by linear combination. This proves the remainder theorem; the case $P(a)=0$ is the factor theorem. Note this proof technique also shows $a\in\Bbb Z,\,P(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]\implies Q(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$.

Comment: @Cdizzle. I think you are wrong, the book seems to say quite clearly that $P(x)$ is a polynomial, and so $x\mapsto P(x)$ is defined everywhere. BUT the book is misleadingly wrong: as BrianM.Scott has said the division algorithm is $P(X)=(X-r)Q(X)+C$, and from that one can deduce $P(\alpha)=(\alpha-r)Q(\alpha)+C$ for every real number $\alpha$, and from that one can deduce, *provided $\alpha\not=r$*, that $P(\alpha)/(\alpha-r)=Q(\alpha)+C/(\alpha-r)$. To write it backwards as your  book does is - as you have discovered - a nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

> > By the division algorithm there exists a quotient polynomial $Q$ having degree one less that that of $P$ and a remainder polynomial of degree $0$ (i.e., a constant $C$) such that $$\frac{P(x)}{x-r}=Q(x)+\frac{C}{x-r}.$$

It is strange that the author is not simply specifying the division algorithm as $P(x)\equiv(x-r)Q(x)+C.$

> > Thus $$P(x)=(x-r)Q(x)+C,\tag2$$
>
> The first equation is only true for $x-r\neq0,$ so the last equation would be $P(x)=(x-r)Q(x)+C,$ where $x\neq r,$

We can actually still show that equation $(2)$ in fact holds for all of $\mathbb R.$

Rewriting it: $$P(x)-(x-r)Q(x)-C=0.\tag{2a}$$ Since $(2\text a)$ holds for every member of $\mathbb R{\setminus}\{r\},$ it has more solutions than the degree of $P.$ So, by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, the LHS must be the zero polynomial, which is identically zero. Therefore, $$P(x)\equiv(x-r)Q(x)+C,$$ as required.